# Text wrap not working on Label inside wrappers - CSS

Tags: css, asp.net, word-wrap

I have some scrolling elements which are set up with some CSS. It all works fine but in the following code, I need lblStallMessage1 to have a max width of 200px so that text over that width will wrap around to the next line. I have tried adding..

```
word-break: break-word; max-width:200px;
```

to the `<p>` which surrounds the Label control. I've also tried it inside the Label Control itself
But nothing is changing.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <section class="horizontal-scroll">
        <div class="item" id="item1" runat="server"><asp:HyperLink ID="hypStall1" runat="server" ><asp:Image ID="imgStall1" width="260px" ImageUrl="~/files/images/car1.gif" runat="server" /></asp:HyperLink><asp:HyperLink ID="hypStall1Avatar" runat="server" ><asp:Image ID="imgStall1Avatar" style="position:relative; float:left; margin-top:-70px; margin-right:-70px;" width="100px" runat="server" /></asp:HyperLink><p style="margin-right:0px;"><asp:Label ID="lblName1" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label></p><p style="position:relative; float:left; margin-top:-340px; margin-right:-70px;" width="100px"><asp:Label ID="lblStallMessage1" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label></p></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS..

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background-image:url(images/field.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
.horizontal-scroll {
     overflow: hidden;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
     padding: 0px 0;
     height:380px;
 }
.item {
     border: 0px solid #333;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 260px;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 20px 0px;
     font-size: 20px;
     margin-left: 50px;
     margin-bottom: 60px;
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the html result page with its css

Comment: @AlanM Not sure what you mean? The URL?

Comment: The html code contains asp ASP.NET Web Forms Label such as  "asp:Label" element that is rendered on the server as in the case of java JSP tag. The rendered page or the result page on the client will contains pure html element. Can we see the result client page on the browser. This is what I want to be posted

Comment: @AlanM have you scrolled to the very end of the code above? You will see the asp:Label. I will see if I can get the results client page.

Comment: Good to hear from you. Yes please try to get the result page with its css